# Change background image via a button from an image selection in a modal in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal

I've created an editing button which opens up a modal with a bunch of images, and after I select one of those images I want to set it on background via a button. (Something like the editing button from google chrome home page when you want to change the background https://ibb.co/K0m7Cfq). But I don't really know how to modify the background: for images url.

***Here is the css for background:***

```
.masthead {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    min-height: 35rem;
    padding: 15rem 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(22, 22, 22, .3) 0, rgba(22, 22, 22, .7) 75%, #161616 100%), url(../img/planet_sky.jpg);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-size: cover
}
```

***And here is the html:***

```
<header class="masthead">

    <!--Editing button-->
    <div align="right">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mx-auto" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changeBackground">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>
    </div>      

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="changeBackground" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header text-center">
                        <h4 class="modal-title w-100 font-weight-bold">Select background</h4>

                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">

                        <input type="image" src="https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687" height="200" width="230" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">

                        <input type="image" src="https://pennyandjohninoz.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/icons-of-australia-3-sydney-opera-house.jpg" height="200" width="230" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">

                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer d-flex justify-content-center">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary mx-auto">Set background <i class="fas fa-paper-plane-o ml-1"></i></button>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer that I wanted, but I gave up on Set background button:

***I created and added this javascript in head:***

```
    <script>
    function changeBackground1(imageUrl){
        document.getElementById('backgroundXD').style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(22, 22, 22, .3) 0, rgba(22, 22, 22, .7) 75%, #161616 100%), url("+imageUrl+")";
    }
    </script>
```

***I added the backgroundXD id in header and used it in script for changing the background from masthead css:***

```
<header class="masthead" id="backgroundXD">
...
</header>
```

***And I also added onclick into inputs just to change background image by clicking the preferred image from modal:***

```
<input onclick="changeBackground1('https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687')"
    type="image" src="https://s.ftcdn.net/v2013/pics/all/curated/RKyaEDwp8J7JKeZWQPuOVWvkUjGQfpCx_cover_580.jpg?r=1a0fc22192d0c808b8bb2b9bcfbf4a45b1793687" height="150" width="230" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">

<input onclick="changeBackground1('https://pennyandjohninoz.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/icons-of-australia-3-sydney-opera-house.jpg')"
    type="image" src="https://pennyandjohninoz.files.wordpress.com/2011/10/icons-of-australia-3-sydney-opera-house.jpg" height="150" width="230" style="padding-right: 3px;padding-bottom: 3px;"  class="img">
```

Comment: What version of Bootstrap? And are you sure you don't want to use a jQuery based approach?

Comment: I'm using 3.4.0 version, but how I edited and added the answer, this doesn't matter anymore. I still thank you for your time and attention .